HttpClient using PFX transport certificate to stablish connection to third part application
I have an Asp.Net core app which has a lot of PFX certificates, those certificates are added as resource to the application, each certificate has a specific client. This Asp.net app is responsible to validate the user through username/password, retrieve the stored PFX certificate and submit a POST request to another application, which I don`t have access to.
Everything works fine when running on localhost, however, when I deploy the solution(I`m deploying it in Ubuntu and IIS) I receive SSL exception which states the connection was not possible to be stablish.
I have performed a few tests and came to the conclusion that it is not the third part server which is refusing connection, but the deployment server. Could someone provide me some help on how to solve this?
this is my C# code:
X509Certificate2 certificate;
string certificatePassword = "myPassword";

var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyApplication.identification_certificate.pfx";
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
  byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
  await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  certificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes, certificatePassword);
}


HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
 // Set the content type
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

 // Make the request
 string url = _configuration["Company"] + "/GetServicedUserInfo/";
 HttpResponseMessage rsp = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(xmlRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"));  //<< Exception happens here
 string responseContent = await rsp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
response.Structure = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientResponse);

Ubuntu exception message:
InnerException = {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsy...
If someone could provide me an insight, I would really appreciate it!
thank you in advance..
Manually install the certificate,
add the certificate into trusted authority,
change the call from RestSharp to System.Net.Http,
Use one of the PFX as DNS SSL server

Get a Wireshark/tcpdump trace of the Client and Server Hello packets. Look for the TLS version, cipher suites and hash suites offered on each side, and check if there's a mismatch. Some bad practices here: don't hard-code the PFX password, if you need to encrypt it then have the user enter the password, otherwise don't bother encrypting.  Don't set SslProtocols, allow the system to decide the best one. ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback  .... => true means you are blindly accepting whatever server responds and not checking its certificate. HttpResponseMessage needs a using.

This error message indicates a problem with SSL certificate validation, the SSL certificate used by your application was not recognized as valid because it was signed by an untrusted certificate authority. To resolve this issue, you need to manually add the self-signed certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on the local computer.

As commented by  @Charlieface, have a look here.
You see the exception in PostAsync because .NET initiates and negotiates SSL protocol with the server under the hood. To peek at that, you'll need to expand ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback, for example:
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (_, cert, chain, policyErrors) =>
        {
            if (policyErrors.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable))
            {
                // certificate not provided for validation; cannot continue
                return false;
            }

            if (policyErrors is SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                // certificate accepted
                return true;
            }

            if (policyErrors.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch))
            {
                // certificate failed CN name check
            }

            var hasChainErrors = policyErrors.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors);
            if (hasChainErrors)
            {
                // certificate generated policy error(s)
                // log using policyErrors.ToString()

                // certificate rejected (HTTPS reject)
                return false;
            }

            // certificate accepted (TLS check passed)
            return true;
        };


Thank you for your answer!
I`ve added the code you provided and saw it was an issue with certificate chain. After adding CA to ca-certificates folder on localhost, it work, however, after deploying the application, the server still giving SSL exception and it is not even calling the custom event handler for validating it..

If it is not hitting this callback, then there is another callback that may help. See ASP.NET's documentation here -- scroll down to Handler Events section for the code. The example demonstrates one event OnCertificateValidated. You can add another event: OnAuthenticationFailed. The Exception property of the event's context will tell you the issue if the callback is hit.

So.. I`ve added your suggestions in the code and managed to find out that the issue was that the certificate was not being trusted by the server, which was causing the exception, after exploring it for a while I saw that the CA certificate must be placed at /etc/ssl/certs/ folder to make it trusted, after doing so, the application started running normally!
thank you a lot!
